# How to change state a self.button

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

i try to learn Object Oriendet with Tkinter.
i make a Button Class and try using this but i cant change it's state

this my class

```
class Buton():
    def __init__(self, konum=None, text=None, command=None, cursor="hand2", state="normal", width=None,
                 row=None, column=None, sticky=None):
        print("SELF: ", type(self), self)
        self.konum = konum
        self.text = text
        self.command = command
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.state = state
        self.width = width
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.sticky = sticky
        self.buton_bas()

    def buton_bas(self):
        self.buton = Button(self.konum, text=self.text, state=self.state, command=self.command)
        self.buton.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column, padx=2, pady=5)

    def state_change(self, new_state):
        self.['state'] = new_statew
```

My def and button

```
def print():
    global label
    label = Label(pencere, text=entry.get(), fg="lightgray", bg=darkbg, font=("Times 10"))
    label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=5, )
    Buton.state_change(buton1, "disable")

buton1 = Buton(konum=pencere, text="Print", command=print, row=2, column=0)
```

When i push Print button, it print the text from entry. its ok but i cant change button's state. i take this: TypeError: 'Buton' object does not support item assignment

i try ;

```
self.state = new_state
```

but dont work.. what is wrong?
thanks for help from now

Comment: You have a function called print and it is overriding the built in method `print`. You should rename that function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a lot of errors. I have fixed them. You need to use `<button>["state"] = state`. Try:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class Buton():
    def __init__(self, konum=None, text=None, command=None, cursor="hand2", state="normal", width=None,
                 row=None, column=None, sticky=None):
        #print("SELF: ", type(self), self)
        self.konum = konum
        self.text = text
        self.command = command
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.state = state
        self.width = width
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.sticky = sticky
        self.buton_bas()

    def buton_bas(self):
        self.buton = Button(self.konum, text=self.text, state=self.state, command=self.command)
        self.buton.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column, padx=2, pady=5)

    def state_change(self, new_state):
        self.buton['state'] = new_state
def print():
    global label
    label = Label(root, text="You can change text", fg="lightgray", bg="grey", font=("Times 10"))
    label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=5, )
    Buton.state_change(buton1, "disable")

buton1 = Buton(konum=root, text="Print", command=print, row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: I guess I made some mistakes while trying to transfer only some of the codes here. but when you fixed the point, the problem was solved.
Thank you so much